# Android Studio : How to debug a running process on Android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

We've following option in Eclipse, which allows us to attach debugger to already running process.

[image: Like this in Eclipse]

I'm looking for a similar option in Android studio, Can somebody tell me where we've this option ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android Studio has this option, the icon looks like this: [image]

Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#attachDebug)

Answer (score 2):

[image: android studio]

the one that looks like a phone with a bug in the corner

Answer (score 1):

At the debug button in the toolbar. Here [debugging with android-studio](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) you have all the info.

The process is basically the same :

- Set your breakpoints.
- Run your app in debug mode.
- Use the debug tool window to check objects info.
- Check the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the image below on where to find the icon. A popup window will appear to ask you to which process you want to attach to. Select your app.

[image: Some Description]